# How do I hide a div, if the img src inside the div appears as "img src(unknown)"?

Tags: jquery, html, wordpress

I'm editing a wordpress file and there is a plugin that allows custom headers and works perfectly. But if no header is selected, a large empty space appears in its place and I'm trying to set some jquery to hide the div all together if the source is empty. When I inspect the element with developer tools, the div appears as:

```
<div class="header-image">
  <img src(unknown) height="0" width="0" alt>
</div>
```

So to try to get past this, I'm trying to hide the element with jquery, but I'm not quite sure how to set the parameters to select the unknown element. This is what I have now that does not work:

```
if ( $(".header-image img").attr('src' == 'unknown') ){
    alert('No header image found');
}
```

I just need to find a way to properly select the element and I'll be able to figure it out from there, thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: If that is Really how the HTML appears then there will be no `src` attribute as that is not valid HTML

Comment: Maybe you need to check the plugin

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `attr()` function does not work like that.

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="header-image">
    <img src="" height="0" width="0" alt>
</div>

<script>
    if ( ! $(".header-image img").attr("src") ){
        alert("No header image found");
    }
</script>
```